# Can App.Current.Properties Dictionary Be Used in Xamarin.iOS AppDelegate?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a XF application that uses the Application Properties dictionary within my shared project to save and access simple data values.
My issue is that I am implementing push notifications in the iOS project and need to save the apns and/or firebase tokens to the application properties dictionary so that I can access the token from the shared project, but my app is crashing on start when I hit the line in the following code that saves the token to app properties

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App());

            // Configure Firebase
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

            // Register app for remote notifications
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // On iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Notifications Authorization: {granted}");

                    // If access is granted, save new fcm token to properties
                    if (granted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"ACCESS GRANTED. TOKEN: {Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken}");
                        SaveTokenToProperties(Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken);

                        //// Check if user has granted permission and register for notifications
                        //this.GetNotificationSettings();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------NOTIFICATION ACCESS NOT GRANTED-----------");
                    }
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    // On iOS 9 or earlier
            //    var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            //    var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);

            //    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            //}


            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();



            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        private void SaveTokenToProperties(string token)
        {
            App.Current.Properties["iOSFBMessagingToken"] = token;
            App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
        }
```

To make things even more complicated, the app does not crash when connected to the debugger on my mac host, but only when my iphone is disconnected from the debugger.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the exception that causes the crash?

Comment: I have checked shared `SaveTokenToProperties` method in iOS `AppDelegate.cs` , that works . And also can retrieve the saved data in Xamarin Forms . You can share more error info or log here .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thank you for checking the `SaveTokenToProperties` method. Unfortunately, the crash only occurs when not connected to the debugger so I must rely on crash logs, but for some reason my app is not leaving any crash logs when I check under my device in "devices and simulators" on my dev mac.

Comment: @Nurupo-Ga You can add breakpoint to check program running to where place , and also can check the device log (*View->Other Windows->Device Logs*) whether can find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue finally fixed itself after various combinations of VS for Mac, Mono on dev Mac, and Mono on dev PC.

So the answer to my actual question is YES, `App.Current.Properties` methods (including `SaveTokenToProperties`) do work in the platform-specific projects for reading and writing simple data, and this data can be accessed and modified by any other project in the XF solution.